# Awk split use array later in bash

Tags: bash, awk

If I have this awk command...

```
echo $line | awk '{split($0,array,"|")}'
```

...how can I use array later in the bash program?  If I try to print out information from the array later it's just empty.

Comment: you can't it's an awk variable.

Comment: the best you can do is output the arr values you need and capture them in the shell, i.e.`bashVars=$(echo "$line" | awk '{n=split($0,arr,"|"); print arr[1] " " arr[n] }' ) ` . for example will print the first and last value from each line and assign to a single shell var `bashVar`. You can get fancy and declare that var as an arr var if need be. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` array contents outside of `awk` if you print it:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a line < <(echo 'o|p|s' | awk '{split($0,array,"|"); for (i in array) print array[i]}')
declare -p line
# OUTPUT: declare -a line='([0]="o" [1]="p" [2]="s")'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't access awk variables outside of awk, but you can do the same using bash arrays directly

```
$ IFS='|' read -r -a array <<< "a|b|c"; echo ${array[1]} 
b
```

Answer (score 1):

An other solution in bash if I presume that fields haven't got space then only 1 assignment.

```
ln="apple|lemon|orange|strawberry"    # eg

v=(${ln//|/ })     # substitute | with " " and vectorising with () 
# Now we are ready

# checking it:
for((i=0;i<${#v[@]};i++));do echo ${v[$i]}; done
apple
lemon
orange
strawberry

#or:
for i in ${v[@]}; do echo $i; done
apple
lemon
orange
strawberry
```

If we have some space but no underline "_" we need 3 steps.

```
ln="api ple|l em  on|ora  nge|s traw   berry"
echo "$ln"
api ple|l em  on|ora  nge|s traw   berry
ln=${ln// /_}                             # 1st
echo "$ln"
api_ple|l_em__on|ora__nge|s_traw___berry
v=(${ln//|/ })                            # 2nd
for i in ${v[@]}; do echo $i; done
api_ple
l_em__on
ora__nge
s_traw___berry
for((i=0;i<${#v[@]};i++));do v[$i]="${v[i]//_/ }"; done  # 3rd
for((i=0;i<${#v[@]};i++));do echo "${v[$i]}"; done
api ple
l em  on
ora  nge
s traw   berry
```